# Using JOI How to define recursive array of objects validation with n depth

Tags: joi

```
let obj = Joi.object().keys({
      "id":  Joi.string().required(),
      "array": Joi.array().items(obj).required()//array contains multiple
});
```

is there any way to define recursive array validation in JOI obj.array contains n number of obj

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recursive schemas can be achieved using Joi's [`lazy(fn)`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#lazyfn---inherits-from-any) function. The following example from the documentation can be adapted to your schema however I'm not sure how you'd be able to define a max depth.

```
const Person = Joi.object({
    firstName: Joi.string().required(),
    lastName: Joi.string().required(),
    children: Joi.array().items(Joi.lazy(() => Person).description('Person schema'))
});
```

Comment: Be aware that if you are using Joi 16.0.0 or higher, Joi.lazy() function was renamed to Joi.link() Change: https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/1968 Docs: https://hapi.dev/module/joi/api/?v=17.1.1#linkref

Comment: @MarMass dead hapi link, https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.6.0#linkref